# Raspberry Pi 4 - Ubuntu Server 22.04 - HEADLESS Static IP Configuration

Tags: 22.04, ethernet, raspberrypi, static-ip

I have a Raspberry Pi 4.

I want to burn an SD card with Ubuntu Server 22.04, with ETH0 configured STATIC IP 192.168.0.10. NO DHCP. (SSH enabled)

Headless, meaning no screen, no keyboard, no mouse. Just power cable, sd card and ethernet cable. There is NO DHCP on the other side of the ethernet cable. I need to have a STATIC IP.
[image]

Is there *something* I can write to the any of the files in BOOT to achieve this result?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's functionally impossible to burn a Ubuntu 22.04 Server image on an SD card, and modifying a file on BOOT to give ETH0 a Static IP, while specifying a WETH0 ssid network to connect to.

As far as I can tell, Ubuntu was designed to use DHCP on first startup, and was designed to brick the network configuration if you try to use a Static IP. It is impossible to connect to a newly booted headless Ubuntu Server on a raspberry pi without an IP scanner.

The power port has a serial interface where you could do the configuration or look the IP using a serial terminal, but your USB host must provide enough power for the raspberry pi, my laptop can't do it for RPI4.

Things i tried:

- Writing on config.txt like i would successfully do on Raspbian
- Writing "ip=192.168.1.10::192.168.1.199:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off" to "boot/commandline.txt" makes ETH0 static, but bricks other network configurations.
- Various guides directed me to create a file with a name in BOOT, claiming ubuntu would look up that file to configure the network, none of that worked

Things that work:

1. use Raspberrypi imager to configure credential, SSID and SSH
2. use an IP scanner to try and find your raspberry pi in the network
3. You can use either Wifi, or a LAN with a DHCP where you have the right to IP scan the network